# Determine relationship between objects with java 8 streams api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

recently I solved the following problem:

Given a chronologically ordered list of LocalDateTime, find the average duration between neighbours.

I did the following:

```
@Test
public void canCalculateAverageDuration() {
    final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    final List<LocalDateTime> localDateTimes = Arrays.asList(now, now.minusHours(5), now.plusMinutes(2));

    final List<Duration> durations = new ArrayList<>();
    localDateTimes.stream()
        .sorted()
        .reduce((first, second) -> {
            durations.add(Duration.between(first, second));
            return second;
        });

    final OptionalDouble averageNanos = durations.stream()
            .mapToDouble(Duration::toNanos)
            .average();

    final Duration average = Duration.ofNanos((long) averageNanos.orElse(0.0));
    assertThat(average).isEqualTo(Duration.parse("PT2H31M"));
}
```

I wonder if the problem could be solved in a more elegant way, for example: I would like to avoid the List of durations if possible. What do you think?

Comment: No, not really. Stream is a pipe where only one element at a time is available, it cannot "lag" to the side and give you two elements. However, you don't actually need streams for your first part at all.

Comment: Maybe if you write custom collectors. But not worth the complexity

Comment: @user7, there are libraries which build on top of `Stream` API and provide windowing by pairing up current element with the one which is seen some while ago. But they aren't a Stream API. A collector would do something, but it would be a collector, so essentially the same thing with a list, just obstructed. Stateful `map()` will also do the trick, albeit that's going against what stream expert group recommends for API usages.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: What do you mean by "you don't actually need streams for your first part at all."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this:

```
Collections.sort(localDateTimes);
final double average = IntStream.range(0, localDateTimes.size() - 1)
    .mapToLong(l ->
        Duration.between(
            localDateTimes.get(l),
            localDateTimes.get(l+1))
        .toNanos())
    .average().orElse(0.0);
assertThat(Duration.ofNanos((long) average)).isEqualTo(Duration.parse("PT2H31M"));
```

Comment: It's of no real use to start from `LongStream`, technically, because `List::size` range is `int`. It can be `IntStream.range` just the same.

Comment: Since I am mapping to a long value (toNanos()) I need the LongStream, because long cannot be converted to int.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this just using iterations (i.e. not using Streams):

```
@Test
public void canCalculateAverageDuration() {
  final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
  final List<LocalDateTime> localDateTimes = Arrays.asList(
      now,
      now.minusHours(5),
      now.plusMinutes(2)
  );
  localDateTimes.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());

  LocalDateTime previous = null;
  LongSummaryStatistics stats = new LongSummaryStatistics();
  for (LocalDateTime dateTime : localDateTimes) {
    if (previous == null) {
      previous = dateTime;
    }
    else {
      stats.accept(Duration.between(previous, dateTime).toNanos());
    }
  }

  final Duration average = Duration.ofNanos((long) Math.ceil(stats.getAverage()));

  assertThat(average).isEqualTo(Duration.parse("PT2H31M"));
}
```

Whether or not this is more elegant is subject to personal preference, but this version uses no intermediate collections at least.